# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden in AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication() in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are using Facebook / Twitter account for logging in to our MVC web app. If I'm running the application directly (pressing F5); everything is working fine. But after setting in IIS, Its throwing 403 forbidden error in below line for Facebook.

> AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();

For Twitter also same error is throwing in below line

> OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow but please note that saying "please respond soon" is very impolite as a new user. People help on SO because they want to and give up their time to do it, the fact that YOU have an urgent problem is unlikely to make people look into it more quickly

Answer (score -1):

This problem got solved. This happened because the domain we are using, don't have permission to access Facebook or Twitter . So need to give the credentials for access the social media sites.

After setting the application in IIS , Click Application Pool (in Left Pan) --> select your application pool (from Middle Pan) -->. Click Advance Settings (Right) under Edit Application Pool .

In Advance Settings dialogue --> Process Model --> Change the Identity --> Custom Account and give your credentials. That's all...